# Buying an amount of product X must add a product Y

Tags: commerce

I have a shop where a product (lawn/turf) can only be bought with an additional package (Europalette). When users buy 1-50 items there must be one Europalette packaging automatically added into the cart. If the amount is 51-100, two Europalette packages must be added.

Europalette is also a product the users buy. So both have to be combined as explained before.

I tried the [Pado](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pado) and [Vado](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_vado) modules, but I can't get them to work. I also tried the Rules module, but there are no right rules for commerce.

I can't put it into shipping because it has to be a product; some users keep the Europalette packages and some will bring them back and get a refund.

Comment: No hint so far ;(

Comment: What is your Drupal version ? With Drupal 8, 9, or 10, it should be easier to use the cart event subscriber.